# value of inverse function

Tags: inverse, lambert-w

First day at university and some high school math, to "refresh".
I need to find value $f^{-1}(12)$ of inverse function of 
$f(x)=5+x+\ln(x-6)$

Whatever I tried, I did not go far. Finally I found out about Lambert W function. We have never mentioned it at school, or I was sick that day :-P. 
This is what I did.

First subtract $11$ from both sides:

$$y=5+x+\ln(x-6)$$

$$y-11=x-6+\ln(x-6)$$

substitute:

$$x-6=Z$$

$$y-11=Z+\ln Z$$

exp:

$e^{y-11}=Z e^Z$  Lambert $W$ function:

$$Z=W(e^{y-11})$$

then I bring back subs:

$$x-6=W(e^{y-11})$$

$$x=6+W(e^{y-11})$$

Now, if I substitute y with 12, I get

$$x=6+W(e)$$

I also found a way how to calculate this in Python and got two values for $W(e)$:
$1.76322281532$ and 
1.76322284514

Which gave me results
$x=7.76322281532$
and 
$x=7.76322284514$

At this point I wanted to verify the result and plugged x back into original function hoping to get y=12. And I got y=13.33.

I must have made a mistake but cannot find it.

Or I made more than one mistake?

Comment: If it's your first day at university dont't try to do anything too advanced. Just try to guess the answer and try to argue why an inverse function exists.

Comment: Since $\color{#C00}{1}\cdot e^{\color{#C00}{1}}=\color{#090}{e}$, $\operatorname{W}(\color{#090}{e})=\color{#C00}{1}$.

Comment: Now it looks easy :-). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also observe $f$ is monotonic, and try your luck (pardon, intuition) checking "easy" values. 
One value of the argument  for which the logarithm is easy to calculate is $1$: you could then check $x = 7$ (as the argument of your logarithm is $x-6$) and verify $f(7) = 12$.

In reference to your approach, after finding the solution above I started to wonder if  $W(e) = 1$ (I am not too conversant with the Lambert W function) and that indeed seems the case, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function, "Special Values" section, you might want to check your Python code.

Comment: Right! W(e) is indeed 1. I will need to  look at the code. With this correction, everything matches. I supposed that there was simpler way to do it, but I just did not see it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Good hint for uni math is that questions will never have answers requiring maths above your grade level, which Lambert's W function definitely is.

Note that if $f(x)=y$, then $f^{-1}(y)=x$. So $f^{-1}(12)$ can just be found by setting $12=5+x+\ln(x-6)$, and you can take it from there.

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed from here. I just found that this could be done using Newton method and that is beyond high school level. I think at this time, the best approach is smart guessing, which is probably what prof expects from students. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: No need to try and solve it using Newton's method! What I meant to say is I think the intention was for you to get to a certain stage then use guess and check. When you have written it as I have above you can remember that $$ln(1)=0$$ and see that $$x=7$$ works or just try some numbers and find it. Point being I think that they want to build "seeing the answer".